# how to check value on each loop by class based on database with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

let's said i have a form for `Quantity` input with class `txt-qty`, and it will be loop based on data from database.

Than i want trying to check the value of quantity should not be `0`, but if one of the quantity is bigger than `0` it will be `true`

this is my code that what i have tried :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input_qty = false;
    $('#checkout').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       var qty =  $('.txt-qty').each(function(){
           $(this).val();
       });
         if(qty > 0){
           input_qty = true; 
         }else{
           input_qty = false;
         }
         if(input_qty == false){
           alert('You must input one of quantity from the menu list');
         }else{
            this.submit();
         }

      });
   });
</script>
```

in my script if i alert `qty` it would be return `[object],[object]`.

guys can you help me how to check one of the value of quantity should not be `0`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying that at least one of the `.txt-qty` fields must have a value > 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to check that at least one of the `.txt-qty` fields has a value > 0, then you can use [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get a true array from your jQuery object and then [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if any field's value is > 0:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkout').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$('.txt-qty').get().some(function(e) { return $(e).val() > 0; })) {
        // Gets array ---^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //                       | Checks for at least one with a value > 0
            alert('You must input one of quantity from the menu list');
        } else {
            this.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

That relies on implicit conversion of the string value to a number; you might consider using `parseInt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#checkout').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
       var qty =[];
        $('.txt-qty').each(function(){

           if(parseInt($(this).val(),10) <= 0 )
                {
               qty.push($(this).val());
               }
       });

         if(qty.length > 0){  // check this
           input_qty = true; 
         }else{
           input_qty = false;
         }
         if(input_qty == true){
           alert('You must input one of quantity from the menu list');
         }else{
            this.submit();
         } 


      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type='text' class='txt-qty' />
 <input type='text' class='txt-qty' />
 <input type='text' class='txt-qty' />
 <input type='text' class='txt-qty' />
 <input type='text' class='txt-qty' />
 <input type='text' class='txt-qty' />

<input type='submit' id='checkout'/>
    </body>


</body>
</html>
```